# What are the applications of the Wehrl entropy in quantum information?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-optics

Can you  show me some important applications of the Wehrl entropy, with brief explanations or some helpful links? Specifically, in quantum dynamics or quantum information.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/656256/2451

Comment: [This talk](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/9entropy.pdf) might help you. The Wheel entropy is n uncontrolled semiclassical approximation of the exact quantum von Neumann entropy (when that entropy is recast in phase space). It is popular because of its [simplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wehrl_entropy), which, however, turns out to be an oversimplicfication.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Hi. What i understood about wehrl entropy so far is, in classical physics we can find position and momentum of particle simultaneously. But in quantum mechanics we cannot because of Heigen Berg principle. If we want to find classical like states for some quantum system, we like to have some probability distribution function for this  which can tell about position and momentum simultaneously. We have that function named as Husimi function. Entropy in phase space will then be defined as a Wehrl entropy in terms of Husimi function.

Comment: @CosmosZachos Have i understood the concept  right? Still I am confused that what is this wehrl entropy tells us. If someone ask me to explain wehrl entropy, what should i tell him?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have seen the mathematical form of Wehrl entropy.  But I need the intuitive explanation for it. Waitng for your reply. Regards.

Comment: Wehrl's [review article](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.50.221) is quite well-written, and discusses the coherent state applications and the semi-classical approximation involved.

Comment: @CosmasZachos  Hey I am reading the article you mentioned above. In that article Wehrl has talked about negativity of "classical" entropy. But previously  I was  reading other article. There Wehrl entropy were defined in terms of Q function and its was also written that we prefer Q function over Wigner function for defining Wehrl entropy because entropy cannot be negative. So why Wehrl does not used Q function? I mean we are using Q function just for our convenience but we can define Wehrl entropy in other way too?

Comment: @CosmasZachos  Also what is meaning of "classical" entropy of quantum state?  I got that planck constant goes to zero. But what this entropy is tell ing about state?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I am sorry, I am disturbing you. I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated, I am ignorant of applications of this entropy, since I dislike it, so some user of it should be given a fair chance to address your question. Wehrl's RevModPhys 1978 article is pretty well-written, but he does not go into applications. I assume students of the classical limit via coherent states use it a lot.

It is an uncontrolled semi-classical approximation of the "correct", fully quantum, well-understood von Neumann entropy. There are good Wikipedia articles on all of them. My [talk here](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/9entropy.pdf) and the primary paper it outlines might be of use, as it covers simple examples.

The language it and Wehrl use for Quantum Mechanics is the
[phase-space formulation of QM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation),
based on the [Wigner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution), $W(x,p)$, the representation of von Neumann's operator $\hat \rho$ in phase space, multiplying with the tell-tale [star product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_product). Thus, operator traces map to phase-space integrals, and operator multiplications map to *-multiplications, e.g. $\hat \rho ^2 \mapsto W\star W$, etc...

A summary of this formulation may be found [here](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf). This language/representation change is invertible, so the von Neumann entropy, positive semi-definite, with its logarithm of operators, maps to a messy expression involving *-functions, defined as a suitable Taylor-Mercator expansion of *-powers as above. Real messy...

Now, *W*  can take negative values in small phase-space regions (with area smaller than ℏ, so, then, very "quantum"; not to worry: the uncertainty principle hides this), and, unless one is very careful, one hits upon logarithms of negative numbers, which nobody wishes on a human.

There is a "fix", namely using the equivalent [Husimi Q function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husimi_Q_representation), which *is* positive semidefinite; but at a major risk of confusion. The point is its appropriate *-product, Ω, not written explicitly here, is a nightmarish mess, and has distinctly inferior properties than that of *W*; it, also, depends on ℏ.

In terms of these, the von Neumann entropy, up to normalizations and shifts, is something like
$$
\int\!\! dx dp ~~ Q(x,p)~~ Ω ~~ \ln_Ω Q(x,p),
$$
really impossible to evaluate, and basically discuss.

At this point, Wehrl suggests (effectively: never in such words!) that he drop the Ωs from the above expression, to get a two-variable classical [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy)
$$
\int\!\! dx dp ~~ Q(x,p) ~~  \ln  Q(x,p),
$$
which is well-defined, gives a good logarithm, and is easy to handle.

*Q*  depends on  ℏ, but it can now be regarded as a bona-fide classical distribution probability, semi-positive definite, and is well-defined for vanishing  ℏ; it is now ignorant of the uncertainty principle, unlike *W*. From this point on,  Wehrl  can compare this *S* to classical entropies and study its behavior w.r.t. both vN and classical Liouville functions, its lower bound of 1, etc...

But you saw how *some* ℏ s were sacrificed to get to this expression, and some not! In the vanishing ℏ classical limit, all is fine, and I believe up to suitable shifts, he finds that this expression above bounds the vN entropy from above, that is it is less informative than vN, with all this forfeiting of quantum information.

It is easy to study, and so an entire generation of superb mathematical physicists have studied its nice properties, referred to in the WP article, and applied to prototype coherent state and Bloch sphere settings. But you are aware of the above original sin. In my talk, and paper, I am careful to use *W* and (almost) its superior product, instead.

Perhaps I am wrong, but I believe all of those were "born" to bound the real vN entropy from above: the limit to our ignorance on mixed states. (For pure states, the vN entropy vanishes and we don't care.)

Comment: Cosmas Zachos  Thankyou so much Sir!